# How to scroll list view & select specific positional element in appium?

Tags: listview, scrollview, scrollto, android-uiautomator, appium-android

[this is the screenshot to scrollable page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKvwI.png)

please see the screenshot
**Following is my code**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("co.nworks.leaveapp:id/txt_select_project")).click();

    MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
            "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.CheckedTextView\").clickable(true).index(6)).scrollIntoView("
                    + "new UiSelector().text(\"Phantom Hydraulics Hub(20170817-001)\"))"));
    //Thread.sleep(2000);
    element.click();
```

Now I, am able to scroll & select the element, but the problem is the list is scrolling little slowly & not reaching it till the last element? please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void swipeToBottom() {
<<sleep for some pre-defined period>>
mDriver.swipe(1250, 1250, 1250, 250, 2000);  //coordinates may vary based on screen size
}
```

Write a for loop[for pre-defined number of swipes], within which -
Search for the element [based on text or any other criteria including UIAutomator search]
If element found, break from for loop.
If not found, call swipe function [above code] and search again[step 1]